# getNeighboringCellInfo() returning null list

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I'm struggling a little trying to get neighbour cells info (for the current cell info, everything works fine):

```
mTelephMgr=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
neighbours=mTelephMgr.getNeighboringCellInfo();
```

I've tried with 2G/3G networks, with Galaxy S (2.2.1) & Nexus S (2.3.1), and two different carriers but I always get an empty list for neighbours. The networks are GSM based (Spain).

I've been googling for a while, and whereas some people are reporting the same issue, other seem to have the function working perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Found the issue... looks like getNeighboringCellInfo() isn't working on samsung devices... I tried it on a Nexus One and it worked.

Comment: I have a Galaxy Nexus. It does not seem to work for me on this device. Anyone else trying it out on this device?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a phone brand issue, the reason is that using a 3G connection you can't get any neighboring cell info (returns an empty list). You need to switch to 2G to get it.

Comment: Are you sure? It works like a charm on not Samsung phones (Desire HD,Nexus One) on both modes (2G/3G); but it's not working on Galaxy S, even when I switch to 2G.

Comment: I switched to 2G mode on my Galaxy Nexus phone but it does not make any difference. I still do not get any value in the neighboring cells.

Comment: I've tried both on 2G and 3G and it didn't worked on Samsung I9082 seems Samsung has problem in this

Answer (score 0):

Any ways, im not sure if that works. Because your code doesnt return a LIST.
it has to be a list.
This is what i have done:-

```
TelephonyManager teleManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighborInfo = teleManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();       
Log.e("xxxxx", "Size: " + neighborInfo.size()  );
```

This works, because i have used it.
But if anyone gets to know why is the List always empty, please do let me know