# Android - is SignalStrength an Event Class?

Tags: java, android, events, class

I have a little problem with a SignalStrength Android class. Is there a way to use methods from this class without referencing an object from this class in a onSignalStrengthsChanged() method? 
From all the examples I saw, it seems to me that this is an Event Class and that object is created when an event (change of gsm signal strength) occurs and that this is the only way to call methods from this class. Am I right?

```
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
  {
     String power= String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());
     gsmStat.setText("GSM cinr: " +power);
  }
```

What if I want to call methods from this class (and read gsm signal properties) in some other case, for example when I click a button object?

Thank you very much for any help, I'm really stuck with this.

BR,
Z

---

Thank you for clearing this up. I tried to use getNeighbouringCellInfo but for some reason this return 0. And yes I've searched and tried different examples.

```
Tel = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

public void onClick(View v) {
List<NeighboringCellInfo>  neighCell = null; 
neighCell = Tel.getNeighboringCellInfo(); 
NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCell.get(1);
int thisNeighRSSI = thisCell.getRssi();
String rssi=Integer.toString(thisNeighRSSI);
tvRSSI.setText("Test: " +rssi);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The only way to get a relevant SignalStrength object is in the onSignalStrengthChanged method.

You can, however, use the TelephonyManager.getNeighbouringCellInfo method to list surrounding cells and get the signal RSSI power (getRssi).

Answer (score 0):

See: [getNeighboringCellInfo() returning null list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536705/getneighboringcellinfo-returning-null-list)

```
getNeighboringCellInfo()
```

This doesn't seem to work on Samsung devices.

Sorry to put this as an answer, but I cannot add a comment to an existing answer.

As for my answer, you can track the RSSI yourself in a service so that when you press the button, the last recorded RSSI value is returned.  Having said that, I've found that on the Samsung Galaxy I work with, the RSSI value is actually the number of antenna bars (ie. I only get 4 values) and not the actual RSSI.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one and actually I have Samsung Galaxy, but what's confusing me is that I get this result while testing on a emulator so I believe maybe there's an issue with my code since I'm pretty new to all of this. Gotta do a Java revision, I forgot almost all I knew :)