# Retrieve cell towers information Android Java Syntax Error Unexpected Identifier

Tags: java, android, termux

I am trying to run the following code on my Samsung S9 and Huawei P20lite on Termux but I am getting an Syntax error at the first line under static. I run the code by using `ecj filename.java` on Termux. I have seen this code on a similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294545/retrieve-cell-towers-information/39504564#39504564) but nobody was mentioning a syntax error.

```
public static JSONArray getCellInfo(Context ctx){
        TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        JSONArray cellList = new JSONArray();

// Type of the network
        int phoneTypeInt = tel.getPhoneType();
        String phoneType = null;
        phoneType = phoneTypeInt == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM ? "gsm" : phoneType;
        phoneType = phoneTypeInt == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA ? "cdma" : phoneType;

        //from Android M up must use getAllCellInfo
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {



            List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighCells = tel.getNeighboringCellInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < neighCells.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject cellObj = new JSONObject();
                    NeighboringCellInfo thisCell = neighCells.get(i);
                    cellObj.put("cellId", thisCell.getCid());
                    cellObj.put("lac", thisCell.getLac());
                    cellObj.put("rssi", thisCell.getRssi());
                    cellList.put(cellObj);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

        } else {
            List<CellInfo> infos = tel.getAllCellInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i<infos.size(); ++i) {
                try {
                    JSONObject cellObj = new JSONObject();
                    CellInfo info = infos.get(i);
                    if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm){
                        CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                        CellIdentityGsm identityGsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellIdentity();
                        cellObj.put("cellId", identityGsm.getCid());
                        cellObj.put("lac", identityGsm.getLac());
                        cellObj.put("dbm", gsm.getDbm());
                        cellList.put(cellObj);
                    } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                        CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                        CellIdentityLte identityLte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellIdentity();
                        cellObj.put("cellId", identityLte.getCi());
                        cellObj.put("tac", identityLte.getTac());
                        cellObj.put("dbm", lte.getDbm());
                        cellList.put(cellObj);
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
            }
        }

        return cellList;
    }
```

Also, I am trying to run the following code that I found on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536705/getneighboringcellinfo-returning-null-list) as well but I am still getting a syntax error at the end of the first line.

```
TelephonyManager teleManager = (TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighborInfo = teleManager.getNeighboringCellInfo();       
Log.e("xxxxx", "Size: " + neighborInfo.size()  );
```

Comment: this code is written in Java, but `node` can run JavaScript, Java != JavaScript

Comment: I have been trying to run both codes as a Java file with ecj (ecj filename.java) but I am still getting errors.